# Inline-block top align issue; blocks seemingly randomly aligned

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align multiple inline-blocks at the top of my page, but for reasons that are baffling to me, it's not working. The CSS could hardly be cleaner or less, but the top isn't aligning properly. I thought it could be a floating issue, but even after applying a clear:both it doesn't fix this.

Please see the program here:
https://jsfiddle.net/yezwocta/

```css
#page {
  text-align: center;
}

.article {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fafafa;
}

.article img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.source {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="article">
    <a href="https://cnn.com" target="_blank">
      <img alt="News" src="https://loremflickr.com/150/130/news?random=1">
      <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Cable News Network</span>
        <span class="source">CNN</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/" target="_blank">
      <img alt="Firefox browser" src="https://loremflickr.com/150/130/browser?random=2">
      <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Get the Latest Firefox Browser</span>
        <span class="source">Mozilla</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <a href="https://www.kproxy.com/" target="_blank">
      <img alt="kproxy" src="https://loremflickr.com/150/130/proxy?random=3">
      <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Surf the web anonymously and bypass filters</span>
        <span class="source">kproxy</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.article` CSS (the default is `baseline`):

```css
#page {
  text-align: center;
}

.article {
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  vertical-align:top;
}

.article img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 170px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.title {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.source {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div class="article">
    <a href="https://cnn.com" target="_blank">
      <img alt="News" src="https://loremflickr.com/150/130/news?random=1">
      <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Cable News Network</span>
        <span class="source">CNN</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/" target="_blank">
      <img alt="Firefox browser" src="https://loremflickr.com/150/130/browser?random=2">
      <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Get the Latest Firefox Browser</span>
        <span class="source">Mozilla</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="article">
    <a href="https://www.kproxy.com/" target="_blank">
      <img alt="kproxy" src="https://loremflickr.com/150/130/proxy?random=3">
      <div class="content">
        <span class="title">Surf the web anonymously and bypass filters</span>
        <span class="source">kproxy</span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, the images being returned must not be exact dimensions. This worked perfectly!